# Question about The Feynman Lectures II Eq. (14.19)

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

After [Eq. 14.19](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_14.html#mjx-eqn-EqII1419) "You can verify if you wish, by direct differentiation of components, that this
integral for $A$ satisfies $∇ · A = 0$ so long as $∇ · j = 0$, which, as we saw, must happen for steady currents."

I don't understand what does it mean.
If $∇ · j = 0$ then $∇ · A = 0$.

What I have understood (possibly wrongly) is that if I derive the right term from Eq. (14.18) for each component with respect to its direction and add them, then I get $0$.

But if so, how would you get zero? To be clearer, how do you derive the terms on the right with respect to their direction?:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} x} \left(\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0 c^2} \int \frac{j_x(2) \, \text{d} V_2}{r_{12}} \right) + \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} y} \left(\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0 c^2} \int \frac{j_y(2) \, \text{d} V_2}{r_{12}} \right) + \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} z} \left(\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0 c^2} \int \frac{j_z(2) \, \text{d} V_2}{r_{12}} \right)=0.$$

I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me in detail what that means.

Comment: Each integral is a convolution. Change the integration variable so that the ${\vec r}_1$ dependence goes into the $j$ components. Make the derivatives, sum them and you'll get an integral containing $\nabla \cdot \vec j$.

Comment: Hint: use integration by parts to change the variable that $\nabla$ acts on from $\mathbf r_1$ to $\mathbf r_2$.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand very well. Perhaps you could recommend a useful reading to help me understand my query.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Feynman's notation makes things a bit blurry, so I'll rewrite the expressions in a slightly different way, resembling a bit more the notation that Griffiths uses. I believe it will make things easier, since it makes more explicit a lot of tricky steps in this derivation.

Eq. (14.19) can be written as
$$\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 c^2} \int \frac{\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|} \text{d}^3 r'.$$

Instead of using $1$ and $2$, I'm using $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r'}$, so that the distinction between the coordinates that exist outside the integral and the coordinates being integrated over gets a bit clearer. We want to compute $\mathbf{\nabla \cdot A}$, where $\mathbf{\nabla}$ refers to the unprimed coordinates (we might eventually need the one for primed coordinates, which we can write as $\mathbf{\nabla'}$). To compute $\mathbf{\nabla \cdot A}$, we can begin by noticing that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\nabla \cdot A}(\mathbf{r}) &= \mathbf{\nabla \cdot}\left(\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 c^2} \int \frac{\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|} \text{d}^3 r'\right), \\
&= \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 c^2} \int \mathbf{\nabla \cdot}\left(\frac{\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|}\right) \text{d}^3 r',
\end{align}
where we were able to bring $\mathbf{\nabla \cdot}$ inside the integral because we are differentiating with respect to the unprimed variables, but integrating with respect to the primed variables.

To proceed, we employ the identity
$$\mathbf{\nabla \cdot}\left(f \mathbf{v}\right) = \mathbf{\nabla}f \mathbf{\cdot v} + f \mathbf{\nabla \cdot v}. \tag{1}$$
It allows us to conclude that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\nabla \cdot}\left(\frac{\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|}\right) &= \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|}\mathbf{\nabla \cdot j}(\mathbf{r'}) + \mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r'})\mathbf{\cdot \nabla}\left(\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|}\right), \\
&= \mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r'})\mathbf{\cdot \nabla}\left(\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|}\right), 
\end{align}
for we were differentiating with respect to the unprimed coordinates, but the current was a function of the primed coordinates only.

At this stage, we notice that since the only difference between $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r'}$ in the expression $\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|}$ is a sign, and hence we must have
$$\mathbf{\nabla}\left(\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|}\right) = - \mathbf{\nabla'}\left(\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|}\right).$$

Bringing everything together, we find that
$$\mathbf{\nabla \cdot A}(\mathbf{r}) = - \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0 c^2} \int \mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r'})\mathbf{\cdot \nabla'} \left(\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|}\right) \text{d}^3 r'.$$

At this stage, we are nearly done. All that remains to do is to use the fact that $\mathbf{\nabla' \cdot j}(\mathbf{r'}) = 0$ and Eq.(1) to put the current inside the divergence, employ the divergence theorem, and it is done. Since I believe the core of the question was on the other points, and particularly in dealing with the different variables, I'll let you fill in these last details.